# Where is The content shown by RenderBody defined?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Sorry for such a simple question, but in viewing a sitelayout page, where/how  do I find the content that is designated to be shown at the @RenderBody?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be the individuals views themselves that are called from the controller. If you view source on the page that comes up, you should see the full layout code wrapped over the code from the view that's actually being called.